# python metaprogramming

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-module

I'm trying to archive a task which turns out to be a bit complicated since I'm not very good at Python metaprogramming.

I want to have a module `locations` with function `get_location(name)`, which returns a class defined in a folder locations/ in the file with the name passed to function. Name of a class is something like NameLocation.

So, my folder structure:

```
program.py
locations/
    __init__.py
    first.py
    second.py
```

program.py will be smth with with:

```
from locations import get_location
location = get_location('first')
```

and the location is a class defined in first.py smth like this:

```
from locations import Location # base class for all locations, defined in __init__ (?)
class FirstLocation(Location):
    pass
```

etc.

Okay, I've tried a lot of **import** and **getattribute** statements but now I'm bored and surrender. How to archive such behaviour?

---

I don't know why, but this code

```
def get_location(name):
   module = __import__(__name__ + '.' + name)
   #return getattr(module, titlecase(name) + 'Location')
   return module
```

returns

```
>>> locations.get_location( 'first')
<module 'locations' from 'locations/__init__.py'>
```

the locations module! why?!

Comment: This idea is painful just to read. Are you really sure you want to go this route?

Comment: I need to be able to do something like in my program.py example. If there is another route, just let me know! :) Sorry for painful reading, my English is not very good.

Comment: It's not so much the English.  It's the idea.  PLease explain *why* you need this.  Also what does "smth" mean?  Please use backticks `\`` around Python variables with `_` in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need to `__import__` the module; after that, getting an attr from it is not hard.

```
import sys

def get_location(name):
    fullpath = 'locations.' + name
    package = __import__(fullpath)
    module = sys.modules[fullpath]
    return getattr(module, name.title() + 'Location')
```

**Edit**: `__import__` returns the package, so you need one more `getattr`, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__) (and read all the section carefully -- "do as I say not as I do";-).

Comment: (where was no titlecase method so I've used someone's snippet) I got AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FirstLocation'

Comment: please look at my question, I've added additional (painful) info

Comment: brilliant!!! thanks. (again, str has no titlecase method, or i don't know about it)

Comment: It's just `.title()`, not `.titlecase()` -- editing to fix, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
location = __import__('first')
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named first, when I'm returning the location from get_location with your code

Comment: Well, adapt it to whatever the heck you're trying to do, but that's how you import a module using a string as the name.